# Can't get multiple panel plots with chartSeries function from quantod package in R

Tags: r

Jeff Ryan's quantmod package is an excellent contribution to the R finance world.

I like to use chartSeries() function, but when I try to get it to display multiple panes simultaneously, it doesn't work.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

chartSeries (SPX)
chartSeries (SPX, subset="2010")

chartSeries (NDX)
chartSeries (NDX, subset="2010")
```

would normally return a four-panel graphic as it does with the plot() function but in the chartSeries example it runs through all instances one at a time without creating a single four-panel graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use chart_Series() instead of chartSeries()  it is layout() and par() compliant.

Comment: What package is chart_Series() in? It's not recognized with require ("quantmod")

Comment: Alright, found chart_Series() in quantmod documentation, but the function is not recognized when called.

Comment: This answer works for 32-bit R in OSX, but not 64-bit R in OSX

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly, you cannot (unless this changed very recently).

The power of adding new sub-panels comes at the prices of not being able to combine these plots as you otherwise could in base graphics.

But you could re-create them in base graphics and then the `par(mfrow=...)`  etc idioms would be available to you.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I was working on an end-of-day (EOD) overview of markets project and will go another way with it now.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add to Brian G. Peterson's post a working quantmod code example for creating `chart_Series` plots in multiple panels:

```
# download data and copy it into environment
sym_bols <- c("IEF", "VTI", "XLP", "XLF", "XLK", "VXX")
data_env <- new.env()
quantmod::getSymbols(sym_bols, env=data_env, from="2017-01-01")
# create chart_Series plots in multiple panels
x11()
par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
par(mar=c(2, 2, 2, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
eapply(data_env, function(x) {
  plot(quantmod::chart_Series(x["2017-06/"], 
       name=strsplit(colnames(x)[1], split="[.]")[[1]][1]))
})  # end eapply
```

Note that `chart_Series` must be wrapped in `plot`.

Produces the following plot:

[image]